# Can I use Spring cloud contact to test third party (non Java) microservices?

Tags: spring-cloud-contract

We are building a large microservices based application, and two components are third party SaaS based, which we have little visibility

All of our internal components are developed using CDC and Spring Cloud Contracts . It is possible for those saas contracts to change and so we'd like to know if there's any way to use contracts to verify those SaaS services as well?

Answer (score 1):

You can check out my presentation where I talk about it https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=ZyHG-VOzPZg

In general, you can write a test that communicates with the external (saas) api via a WireMock proxy. You'll call the API and register the request and response pairs. Those pairs you could then dump to a stubs jar to reuse. You could run such a test every now to ensure that the stubs are up to date.

You can find an example of such a repo here https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/the-legacy-app/tree/master/stubs_with_proxy